# ./node_exporter: cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, rhel7, prometheus

I am using RHEL7.9 in my Virtual Box. I installed the binary file of **node_exporter** as explained in the official documentation. I tried to run node_exporter using the following command:

```
./node_exporter
```

but it shows me the following error, instead of the output of the documentation:

[image: ERROR: node_exporter: cannot execute binary file]

How to solve it and why is this happening in my machine?

Official Documentation that I followed: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/

[image: commands in documentation]

Comment: Most probably the binary has been compiled for a different architecture. Check your architecture (`uname -i`) and get a matching binary.

Comment: Please  when posting console output / settings format it as "`code`" using [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. Also use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a MacOS binary (`darwin-amd64`). You need to download the correct binary for your OS and architecture - `linux-amd64`.